# SQL server name in hosts file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm developing an ASP.NET application and we're using TFS for source control. Each time we need to change the "data source" in the connectionString to point to our local server during the development. I'm running SQLEXPRESS so I was writing .\SQLEXPRESS in the web.config file and it was working fine. Now we shouldn't modify the web.config file any more and will need to add a record into the hosts file to point the "data source" from the web.config file to my local machine's SQL server. Say, we have "DEVDATABASE" in the web.config as "data source", how should the hosts file line look like for that to work? Something like the following?

.\SQLEXPRESS      DEVDATABASE

This however does not work. Could anybody please help me to understand what's the way it should work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the hosts file (or DNS) to point at a named instance. This is meant to redirect only to a specific machine, not to a specific machine + port number. You could try [creating an alias in the client network utility](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) - you'll also want to make sure that TCP/IP is enabled and that the SQL Browser service is running.

Comment: You can set a named instance in the hosts file. Not sure if it has been updated since the original answer.

Comment: @mli I think you mean a server name. Could you show an example of setting a named instance in the hosts file? For a named instance that is *not* conveniently listening on port 1433?